# Struggling with layout in CSV for draw.io

Tags: orgchart, draw.io

I have created a beautiful org chart in draw.io by using the Arrange > Layout > Org Chart > Single Column Right.

However, I do not know how to put this in a CSV so that this will be done automatically when I import the CSV.

The only options in CSV seem to be these:

```
## Name of layout. Possible values are auto, none, verticaltree, horizontaltree,
## verticalflow, horizontalflow, organic, circle. Default is auto.
#
# layout: horizontaltree
```